# Very custom order using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: iphone, xcode, nssortdescriptor

Let's say I have objects with different statuses. Statuses are from 0 to 2. I need to sort them using NSSortDescriptor in this way:

1

2

0

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this (untested):

```
descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
          initWithKey:@"status"
          ascending:YES
          selector:@selector(customStatusCompare:)] autorelease];

@interface NSNumber (CustomStatusCompare)
- (NSComparisonResult)customStatusCompare:(NSNumber*)other;
@end

@implementation NSNumber (CustomStatusCompare)
- (NSComparisonResult)customStatusCompare:(NSNumber*)other {
  NSAssert([other isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]], @"Must be a number");
  if ([self isEqual:other]) {
    return NSOrderedSame;
  }
  else if (... all your custom comparison logic here ...)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's ok, but could you also help with this "all your custom comparison logic here". I'm a newbie...

Comment: It's an NSNumber, so you'll want the `integerValue` to get to a simple integer. Compare them with <, = and > and return `NSOrderedDescending`, `NSOrderedSame`, or `NSOrderedAscending` based on how you want them to be ordered. In your case, if `[self integerValue]` is 1, then it's always `NSOrderedAscending` (since we already checked for equality). If it's 0, then it's always `NSOrderedDescending`. If it's 2, then you need to check the other value to figure out which to return.

Comment: Can't get descriptor to call (customStatusCompare:) in category.

Comment: What error are you seeing? Are you sure you're compiling the .m file that provides the implementation? Are you including the @interface .h into the file that references `customStatusCompare:`?

Comment: I got it working, the success depends on the order you pass the statuses. I need an independent sorter. Here is my code:

- (NSComparisonResult)customStatusCompare:(NSNumber*)status {
    if ([self isEqual:status]) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
    else if ([self isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if ([self isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
    else if ([self isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return 0;
    
}

@end

Comment: Sorry, it's wrong code. Here is the right one:
 if ([self isEqual:status]) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
    else if ([self isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else if ([self isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
    else if ([self isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return 0;

Comment: That doesn't look right. `if ([self isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]) { return NSOrderedSame; }` seems wrong. You need to actually check the value of `status` in this case. BTW, I would also pull out the value into an `int` and do your work that way rather than generating so many `NSNumber` objects. That's fairly optimized, but this code still gets called a lot.

Comment: I finally got it working, tomorrow will post here the code. :) Thank you Rob for getting me understand the goal.

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom comparator or selector. `NSSortDescriptor` has some methods you should take a look at. From the [NSSortDescriptor Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
+ sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:selector:
– initWithKey:ascending:selector:
+ sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:
– initWithKey:ascending:comparator:
```

You will likely run into problems if you're passing these kinds of sort descriptors to a Core Data fetch request, though.

Comment: We seem to be having these Core Data fetch request "problems". Can you elaborate as to the cause? Core Data is just throwing an exception.

Comment: What do your sort descriptors look like? You can't use a custom selector or comparator with Core Data fetch requests.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. We were trying to use a comparator.