# Is it not possible to sort by a BOOL attribute, using NSSortDescriptor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I need to sort the rows in my sections, from `fetchedResultsController`.

I'm trying to make sure the Entity with lastCell attribute set to `YES`, to be the last shown cell in it's section. Somehow it's always the first? Is this not possible?

Ordering from timeStamp is working great. `lastCell` on the other hand doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastCell"  ascending:NO];
```

Comment: Edited answer in response to your edit

Comment: Did you try ascending:YES for lastCell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the NSSortDescriptor fr the lastCell to be ascending.  After all, False (aka 0) comes before True (1).

Answer (score 0):

What you might try is creating a simple custom comparison method to use. This question would be a good reference for that:

[Very custom order using NSSortDescriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178526/very-custom-order-using-nssortdescriptor)

Comment: Note that such as custom sort descriptor cannot be used with a Core Data fetch request.